# how to correctly convert OccupancyGrid format message to image?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, occupancy-grid, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,all

I want to convert `OccupancyGrid` format message to 'mono8' formt image. Actually,I subscribed `/move_base/local_costmap/costmap` topic ,but the result look like weird, compared with map showed in rviz,it was inversed and rotated .
here is code relative converting proccess ：

```
 def callback(self,data):
     self.width = data.info.width
     self.height = data.info.height
     self.resolution = data.info.resolution
     self.length = len(data.data)
     #self.min_line = []

     #creat an mat to load costmap
     costmap_mat = cv.CreateMat(self.height,self.width,cv.CV_8UC1)

     for i in range(1,self.height):
         for j in range(1,self.width):
            cv.Set2D(costmap_mat,i-1,j-1,255-int(float(data.data[(i-1)*self.width+j])/100*255))
```

Any answer is appreciated .-

edit：

the code given by @Stefan Kohlbrecher shed light on my problem . It was wrong with order `i-1` and `j-1`。here is modified code and it works,

```
for i in range(1,self.height):
            for  j in range(1,self.width):
               cv.Set2D(costmap_mat,self.width-j,self.height-i,255-int(float(data.data[(i-1)*self.width+j])/100*255))
```

Althrough my problem was solved , I am still  confused that the sequence is `self.height-1--->0` rather than `0--->self.height-1` .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163801/how-to-correctly-convert-occupancygrid-format-message-to-image-?/) by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another option would be to use [gridmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/gridmap_2d), it offers conversions between OccupancyGrid messages and OpenCV images.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on 2014-05-12**:
Thank you; I'll check those resources out .